# How many times has an NHL player scored in every game of a playoff series?

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, nhl, postseason, stanley-cup

With the Islanders' Jordan Eberle having accomplished this against the Penguins during the [1st round of the 2018-2019 NHL playoffs](https://www.hockey-reference.com/playoffs/2019-new-york-islanders-vs-pittsburgh-penguins-eastern-first-round.html), how many players have ever gotten a goal (not just a point) in every game of a playoff series before?

Answer (score 1):

This has happened a bunch of times. [2008 conference semifinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Stanley_Cup_playoffs#Western_Conference_Semifinals), [Johan Franzen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johan_Franz%C3%A9n) had 9 goals against the Avs in four games (2, 3, 1, 3 each game).  The record for goals in a series is held by [Jari Kurri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jari_Kurri) with 12 in 6 games (3, 2, 0, 0, 4, 3), but he didn't score in every game.

Comment: Any references at all?

Comment: http://www.nhl.com/ice/page.htm?id=31099 and hockeyreference.com